# Controller API return to Ajax a response with a status 200 but an empty array

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I am totaly stuck with an Ajax request. I m trying to send a response to Ajax with an encoded array to json. Ajax get a status 200 response, but only strings are sent ; not my variables.
I wonder if the probleme is due to the asynchronous... When I test with Postman, i can see the full response but Js give to me : {"recipies":[]}.

Thanks for your help.

Ajax :

```
searchByIngredients: function () {
        console.log('Search for recipies');

        var array = [];
        var ingredients = $('.span-ingredient');
        ingredients.each(function () {
            array.push(this.innerHTML);
        });
        console.log(array);
        console.log(Array.isArray(array));
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: Routing.generate('shopping_list_by_ingredients_ajax'),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(array)
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (null !== response) {
                    console.log('ok : ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log(typeof(response));
                } else {
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
```

Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/by-ingredient-ajax", name="shopping_list_by_ingredients_ajax", options={"expose"=true}, methods={"GET","POST"})
 *
 * @return JsonResponse|Response
 */
public function createShopplistByIngredientsAjax(Request $request, RecipeIngredientRepository $recipeIngredientRepository, RecipeRepository $recipeRepository)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $dataIngredients = json_decode($request->getContent());
        $dataIngredients = $request->getContent();

        // Sorry for this :/
        $arrayIngredients = explode(', ', $dataIngredients);
        $text = str_replace("'", '', $arrayIngredients);
        $text2 = str_replace('[', '', $text);
        $text3 = str_replace(']', '', $text2);
        $recipiesArray = [];

        // Get matching RecipeIngredient
        foreach ($text3 as $data) {

            /**
             * @return RecipeIngredient()
             */
            $recipeIngredients = $recipeIngredientRepository->findBy([
                'name' => $data,
            ]);

            foreach ($recipeIngredients as $recipeIng) {
                $name = $recipeIng->getName();
                $recipeNames = $recipeRepository->findRecipeByKeywwords($name);

                foreach ($recipeNames as $recipeName) {
                    /**
                     * @return Recipe()
                     */
                    $recipies = $recipeRepository->findBy([
                        'id' => $recipeIng->getRecipe(),
                    ]);

                    // Built array with names & ids of recipies
                    foreach ($recipies as $key => $recipe) {
                        $recipeName = $recipe->getName();
                        $recipeId = $recipe->getId();
                        $recipiesArray[] = ['name' => $recipeName];
                        $recipiesArray[] = ['id' => $recipeId];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode([
            'recipies' => $recipiesArray,
        ]));

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }

    return new Response(
        'Something wrong...',
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        ['content-type' => 'text/html']
    );
```

Repository :

```
  /**
     * @return Recipe[] Returns an array of Recipe objects
     */
    public function findRecipeByKeywwords($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->andWhere('r.name LIKE :val')
            ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
            ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony 2.1**

```
$response = new Response(json_encode(array('recipies' => $recipiesArray)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

**Symfony 2.2** and higher

You have special JsonResponse class, which serialises array to JSON:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

//
//

return new JsonResponse(array('recipies' => $recipiesArray));
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html

Comment: Yes. Now you Can also do this : return $this->json([]) (symfony 5) but the result is the same. I ve tried all possibilities to encode to json. I think the issue is somewhere else.. but where ??? Asynchrone ? Im am confused...

Comment: you have tried combining serializer with JsonResponse?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require jms/serializer-bundle
```

After you have installed the package, you just need to add the bundle to your AppKernel.php file:

```
// in AppKernel::registerBundles()
$bundles = array(
    // ...
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
    // ...
);
```

The configured serializer is available as jms_serializer service:

```
$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
$json=$serializer->serialize(['recipies' => $recipiesArray], 'json');
return new JsonResponse($json,200);
```